# When to use "Then"

Tags: adverbs, idiomatic-language

I feel I much use "Then" to relate sentences. I would like to know my usage of "then" is natural in some sentences I made.

Is it possible that the "Then" is redundant and the flow of events is clear without it?

> In the tool we developed, the user first loads an example page in an embedded web explorer. **Then,** he specifies some anchors by selecting elements of the page....
>
> The input of the algorithm is the DOM tree of the webpage, the list of anchors and the contexts created by the user. **Then,** the nodes of the DOM tree are traversed recursively in depth-first manner....
>
> Otherwise, if it has an ancestor which encloses the target section, we can find another anchor within the section which shares this same ancestor. **Then,** by selecting these two anchors from the list of anchors and selecting the “Common Ancestor” option, the context is created.

Answer (score 2):

Those examples sound fine to me. 'Then' can mean 'Once the action just described is complete...' or 'if something is true' i.e. 'Can you get the cat in and THEN feed her' or 'If the cat is in THEN can you feed her?'

Think about an 'if...then...' construct in programming.